# (Drupal) Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/includes/common.inc

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, http-error, drupal-ctools

I have installed quicktabs module and configured it. When I try to implement it using mini-panel, it gives me an error(Please see the attachments).

[image]

I have tried various methods which I found on Google and Drupal, but couldn't solve my problem.

When I looked in Error Logs, I found this.

[Thu Dec 05 15:02:00 2013] [error] [client 130.246.76.109] PHP Fatal error: **Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/includes/common.inc** on line 4465, referer: http://etraining-dev.esc.rl.ac.uk/admin/structure/mini-panels/add/content

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

I figured out that the reason of that error was ctools module. I read somewhere that they have fixed this problem in their latest dev release. So I uninstalled the recommended 7.3 version and installed the 7.1 dev version and it solved this issue.

Thanks